# SQL record exists in another table with LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables TAB A and TAB B and I would like to print 
everything from TAB A and if record exist in TAB B then return 1 or 0
but in TAB B can be multiple records with same id I think I need group this table?

**TAB_A**

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦════╗
║ COLA ║ COLB ║ COLC ║ ID ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬════╣
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CAB  ║ 1  ║
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CFD  ║ 2  ║
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CCD  ║ 3  ║
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CTR  ║ 4  ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩════╝
```

**TAB_B**

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦════╗
║ COLA ║ COLB ║ COLC ║ ID ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬════╣
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CAB  ║ 1  ║
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CFD  ║ 2  ║
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CCD  ║ 3  ║
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CCD  ║ 3  ║
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CCD  ║ 3  ║
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CTR  ║ 4  ║
║ AAA  ║ BBB  ║ CTR  ║ 5  ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩════╝
```

By this example I should have 4 records but LEFT JOINT gives 6

```
SELECT 
       A.*

       , case when B.ID is not null then 1 else 0 end as NEW_COLUMN
FROM 
       TAB_A A 
              left join TAB_B B
                     on A.ID= B.ID
WHERE 
       SOMETHING ....
```

Comment: So you want to eliminate duplicate records right ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword to remove duplicates which might be present in the `TAB_B` table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*,
    CASE WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NEW_COLUMN
FROM TAB_A A LEFT JOIN TAB_B B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You run a query only on TABA but in a subquery you can decide if exists record in TABB so you can return 1 or 0 (as you want)

Try this:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE 
    WHEN
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABB
        WHERE TABB.ID = TABA.ID) > 0
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
FROM TABA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION BY` clause.

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT  A.* ,
            CASE WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END AS NEW_COLUMN, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.ID ORDER BY B.ID) AS row_num
    FROM    TAB_A A
            LEFT JOIN TAB_B B ON A.ID = B.ID
) res
WHERE res.row_num = 1
```